# Is there any way to get available Wifi list in iOS devices in react-native?

Tags: iphone, react-native, wifi

I'm making an application and in it, I require a list of available Wifi for the device. For android, I can get the list of available Wifi with the **react-native-wifi-reborn** package. But for **iOS**, it has no function to get a **list of available Wifi**. For that, I have done lots of R&D but did not find anything. How can I get an available Wifi list for iOS?
Please help me with it.
Thank you.